# Using MSAL to get access token and cache it in SQL DB, without having to sign in using MSAL

Tags: powerbi, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-platform

I want to authenticate AAD users to access powerBi resources through MSAL by using application ID and secret. So i want to get the access token and cache it in SQL Db.

went through the [documentation](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/token-cache-serialization) but it explains the scenario of using MSAL for sign-in. 
also went through the [tutorial](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-2-TokenCache)
i was able to to do the necessary implementations to get the token.

how can i get the access token and cache it, in a scenario like this?

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in other answers, caching tokens are useful in case when you have users signing in, as once the access token expires (typically after 1 hour), you don't want to keep prompting the users to re-authenticate.
So help with these scenarios, Azure AD issues a [refresh token along with an access token that is used to fetch access tokens once they expire](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#refresh-the-access-token). Caching is required to cache these refresh tokens as they are valid for 90 days.

When an app signs as itself (and not signing in a user), the [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) is used and it only needs the app id (clientId) and the credential (secret/certificate) to issue an access token. The MSAL library will automatically detect when the access token expires and will use the clientId/credential combination to automatically get a new access token. So caching is not necessary.

The sample you should be looking at is [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2) one.

Comment: the reason i need to cache the token in a persistent storage is because we are using the master user's access token for other normal users. so for an example user A can be the master user with powerBI access and user B can be a normal user who can just view reports. so user A adds the powerbi instance and reports to the application and authenticate himself and allow user B to view the reports within the application. So user B views the reports with the access token of user A. 
The application sign-in authentication is independent. This is to authenticate users to access PowerBI resources.

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 1):

I'n not sure to understand, I hope these few lines of code will help you.

First, customize token cache serialization :

```
public class ClientApplicationBuilder
{
    public static IConfidentialClientApplication Build()
    {
        IConfidentialClientApplication clientApplication =
            ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(ClientId)
                .WithRedirectUri(RedirectUri)
                .WithClientSecret(ClientSecret)
                .Build();

        clientApplication.UserTokenCache.SetBeforeAccessAsync(BeforeAccessNotification);
        clientApplication.UserTokenCache.SetAfterAccessAsync(AfterAccessNotification);

        return clientApplication;
    }

    private static async Task<byte[]> GetMsalV3StateAsync()
    {
        //TODO: Implement code to retrieve MsalV3 state from DB
    }

    private static async Task StoreMsalV3StateAsync(byte[] msalV3State)
    {
        //TODO: Implement code to persist MsalV3 state to DB
    }

    private static async Task BeforeAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
    {
        byte[] msalV3State = await GetMsalV3StateAsync();
        args.TokenCache.DeserializeMsalV3(msalV3State);
    }

    private static async Task AfterAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
    {
        if (args.HasStateChanged)
        {
            byte[] msalV3State = args.TokenCache.SerializeMsalV3();
            await StoreMsalV3StateAsync(msalV3State);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an example to acquire token (by Authorization Code) :

```
public class MsAccountController
    : Controller
{
    private readonly IConfidentialClientApplication _clientApplication;

    public MsAccountController()
    {
        _clientApplication = ClientApplicationBuilder.Build();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        Uri authorizationRequestUrl = await _clientApplication.GetAuthorizationRequestUrl(ClientApplicationHelper.Scopes).ExecuteAsync();
        string authorizationRequestUrlStr = authorizationRequestUrl.ToString();
        return Redirect(authorizationRequestUrlStr);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> OAuth2Callback(string code, string state)
    {
        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await _clientApplication.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(scopes, code).ExecuteAsync();
        return Ok(authenticationResult);
    }
}
```

Finally, acquire a token silently and use auth result for your API client :

```
public class TaskController
    : Controller
{
    private readonly IConfidentialClientApplication _clientApplication;

    public TaskController()
    {
        _clientApplication = ClientApplicationBuilder.Build();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        IEnumerable<IAccount> accounts = await _clientApplication.GetAccountsAsync();
        AuthenticationResult result = await _clientApplication.AcquireTokenSilent(ClientApplicationHelper.Scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault()).ExecuteAsync();

        //TODO: Create your API client using authentication result
    }
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I've done this for a confidential client application, where I connected to O365 in order to send email.

First, register your app in azure app as the docs say.

Then, set up your confidential client application and use as singleton.

```
var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)                        
    .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)                                                          
    .WithLegacyCacheCompatibility(false)                                                           
    .WithAuthority(AadAuthorityAudience.AzureAdAndPersonalMicrosoftAccount)
    .Build();
    app.AddDistributedTokenCache(services => {
        services.AddDistributedTokenCaches();
        services.AddDistributedSqlServerCache(options => {
            options.SchemaName = "dbo";
            options.TableName = "O365TokenCache";
            options.ConnectionString = sqlCacheConnectionString;
            options.DefaultSlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(90);
        });
    });

    services.AddSingleton<IConfidentialClientApplication>(app);
```

The first time you connect a user, you need to redirect to Microsoft identity. You can create the URL using:

```
var authUrl = await app.GetAuthorizationRequestUrl(new[] { "email", "offline_access", "https://outlook.office.com/SMTP.Send" }).ExecuteAsync();
```

(Check your scopes are what you want)

When they come back to your redirect url you then get the code from query string and acquire the refresh token:

```
var token = await app.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(scopes, code).ExecuteAsync();
```

When you do this, MSAL will cache the access token and refresh token for you, but here's the thing they don't mention: you have to create the table in SQL yourself! If you don't, it just silently fails.

```
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-sql-cache
dotnet sql-cache create "<connection string>" dbo O365TokenCache
```

Once you have the access token the first time you can use the following later

```
var account = await app.GetAccountAsync(accountId);
var token = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, account).ExecuteAsync();
```

When you get the access token the first time, you need to look at `token.Account.HomeAccountId.Identifier` as this is the ID that you need when you call `GetAccountAsync`. For some reason, `GetAccountsAsync` (note the extra "s") always returns empty for me but passing the correct ID to `GetAccountAsync` does return the right one.

For me, I simply store that ID against the logged in user so that I can get that ID at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

You can cache the access token (actually, the library does this already), but it is valid for 1 hour only. So it makes no sense to save it in a database, because it will expire quickly.

You should cache the credentials needed to obtain the token (user name and password, app ID and secret, or certificate) and obtain a token when needed.

Comment: the reason i need to cache the token in a persistent storage is because we are using the master user's access token for other normal users. so for an example user A can be the master user with powerBI access and user B can be a normal user who can just view reports. so user A adds the powerbi instance and reports to the application and authenticate himself and allow user B to view the reports within the application. So user B views the reports with the access token of user A. The application sign-in authentication is independent. This is to authenticate users to access PowerBI resources

Comment: any thoughts on this ?